# Fire iframe type magnificPopup programmatically

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I'm trying to figure out how to implement magnific popup from the onItemClick event of jquery.gantt.  Fortunately, it lets us implement code via a self executing function which it passes `data` to from the clicked element.

What I'm having issues with now is building the appropriate call to magnific popup in order to load an iframe type popup via jquery.  I've tried it a few different ways and unfortunately because I don't have a solid fundamental understanding of either of these jquery plugins (nor jquery for that matter), I'm playing at monkey-see monkey-do.

```
function(data) {
    $.magnificPopup({type: 'iframe',
        iframe: { src: 'http://server/page.aspx?id=' + data}
    }).magnificPopup('open');
}
```

This seems close.  I get `type error: $.magnificPopup is not a function` when I try to fire this function.  How can I fire an iframe type popup born completely out of javascript?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    src: 'something.html'
  },
  type: 'iframe'
});
```

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#public-methods

Comment: Thanks.  It seemed like the example was only for images, given its likeness to the regular image code.